# Center a label on any form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, width, measure, text-rendering

I need to show a form with a centered label (according to form's width and label's text, width, font family and font size). This have been my attempt so far:

```
(Me.Width - TextRenderer.MeasureText("Hello word", New Font("Delius", 10, 
FontStyle.Regular).Width) / 2
```

No matter how much I try, the label doesn't appear centered as it should (label's left and right sides don't appear to be the same size).

Is there another way to measure text no matter which font is used? Thank you.

Comment: That equation wont give you anything that knows it is equidistant from the edges of the form. You need to place the label centrepoint at Form1.Width/2.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the `Autosize` property of your label to False, then either `Dock` the Label Top, Bottom or Fill, or drag it to the full width of the form and set `Anchor` to both Left and Right. Then set `TextAlign` to MiddleCenter.

The `Anchor` property is pretty nifty, because it basically pins the a border of a control to the respective side of the form.
So in our case the left side of the control sticks to the left side of the form, and the right side sticks to the right side of the form.
So if the form is resized, it drags the left and right side of the control with it. Together with the `TextAlign`, this always keeps the text centered.
For this to work, the `AutoSize` functionality of the label needs to be disabled.

An alternative way would be to keep `AutoSize` enabled, center the form on the control, and then *disable* both Left and Right `Anchor`. This would keep the label centered as well, as it now does no longer stick to either side but keeps its relative position.

So: Let the control do the work for you.

[image]

Comment: Now it's properly centered! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I added some additional explaination as well.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a more professional solution:

horizontal centering:

```
 myLabel.Left = (myLabel.Parent.Width \2) - (myLabel.Width \2)
```

vertical centering:

```
myLabel.Top = (myLabel.Parent.Height \ 2) - (myLabel.Height \ 2)
```

add this code on the `myLabel.[SizeChanged][1]` Event handler as well as on its parent `SizeChanged` Event handler

p.s. dont add the codeline before the `InitializeComponent()` method is called or before the control being attached to a parent control.